# Bitfield width in inspect

Tags: origen-sdk

Currently working on a project where the data I am importing for my registers has very long bitfield names.  The current '13' width limit on inspect makes the registers completely unreadable as the first 13 characters are identical.

I have hacked at reg.rb to report inspect in nibbles instead of bytes just by replacing all the 8s with 4s.  If there are no better ideas, I was going to attempt to add something to do this automatically if the bit width is larger than 13.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good idea, maybe also give the user the ability to override the 13 width limit via an environment variable or something?

Maybe a combination would be good:

- Allow the user to increase the width past 13 if they want
- At render time have a look to see if any truncation is happening for the current width/register combination and if so automatically drop down to the nibble view